# How to check links and change them?

Tags: php, html, scripting, tumblr, ifttt

I am working on an Automated Tumblr blog and noticed that you can't post Twitch streams as a video post, however when you embed them you can.

There are going to be multiple users and it will be expanding, so I am trying to automate the script in IFTTT, however, I don't have much scripting knowledge and tried to get this done... didn't work out.

The question:

It all starts with the content link, this can really be any platform. However, all platforms that aren't supported by Tumblr need a different embed.

So what I want is a script (not asking for the script, just help) that can detect what platform the link is from and chooses a path on what it found out.

Basically, a script that checks if it's twitch, run **a**, if it's youtube run **b**, etc.

**If the input contains "Twitch" run**:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        channel: "{channel Name}"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**If YouTube**:

```
<script type="text/html" id="Video URL here">
```

How do I create these checks?

(I know this question is stupid and probably easy, but I am not really big on scripting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the URL string and check it against each keyword to determine if it exists:

```
var urlString = "https://www.twitch.tv/Reco_Mouse";

if(urlString.indexOf("twitch.tv") !== -1) {

  //First, dynamically include the Twitch script tag on the page

  new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
    width: 854,
    height: 480,
    channel: "{channel Name}"
  });
  break;

} else if(urlString.indexOf("youtube.com") !== -1) {

  //Apply necessary steps for YouTube videos

} else if(urlString.indexOf("anothervideotype.com") !== -1) {

  ... //Apply necessary steps for another video type

}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this really helps!